# Select sibling and all the nested particular type of element of that sibling

Tags: css

Suppose this is my markup:

```
<a class="top-category"></a>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Something 1</li>
            <li>Something 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now when `.top-category` is active, I wanna select it's immediate `ul` and all the `ul` inside of that immediate `ul`.

So far I can select the immediate `ul` like that: `.top-category:active + ul {/* css code */}`. But can't figure out how to select the nested `ul`. How can i do that ?

Comment: `.top-category:active + ul ul {}` ?

Comment: @doğukan yeah, it works on codepen. `.top-category:active + ul, .top-category:active + ul ul {}`.
But not working on my actual project :( . may be something is overriding...

Comment: @connexo this is a demo markup which i provide. In my actual project `ul` can be placed in multi-level deep.

Comment: I figure out the problem, i need to use `:focus` pseudo selector also along with `:active`.